# Inconsistent multiplication mechanism in backpropagation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

When doing backpropagation to update biases in a neural network, when to use dot product and when to use entry-wise matrix multiplikation (hadamard product)?

Assume I obtain the following using the chain rule:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_2} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial z_2} \cdot \frac{\partial z_2}{\partial h_2} \cdot \frac{\partial h_2}{\partial w_2} $$

... and the resulting dimensions are the following, respectively:
$$(9, 200) = (9,1) \cdot (9,1)  \cdot (200,9). $$

If they dimensions have to match, I have to entry-wise multiplicate the two first arrays, and then use the dot product between the remaining to factors.

But what is the mathematics behind this? Why can't I use the same multiplication mechanism on all factors?

---

Let the operator '$:=$' indicate the shape of the left hand side.

We have that $\text{input} := (784, 1)$, $\text{target} := (9, 1)$,  $w_1 := (200, 784)$ and $w_2 := (9, 200)$.
Then the shapes become:

$$h_1 = w_1 \cdot \text{input} := (200, 1)$$
$$z_1 = \text{sigmoid}(h_1) := (200, 1)$$
$$h_2 = w_1 \cdot z_1 := (9, 1)$$
$$z_2 = \text{sigmoid}(h_2) := (9, 1)$$
$$L = \sum_{i=1}^9(\text{target}^i - z_2^i)^2 := (1,1)$$

Comment: The shapes of your derivative matrices must be wrong. It would help to write the input and output spaces for the functions $h_2, z_2$, and $L$ explicitly.

Comment: I have now updated my question, @littleO

Comment: I initially wrote the wrong dimensions. That's why I was confused.
The dimensions should look like this:
$$(9, 200) = (9,1) \cdot (9,1)  \cdot (200,9) = (9,9) \cdot (200, 9) = (9, 200)$$

(just moved my answer as a comment)

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer to use as a 'convention' that the gradient of a scalar by a matrix should have the same dimension as the matrix (this is called denominator layout, see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus)).
So
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{W}_2}$ should have the dimension of $\mathbf{W}_2$
In your case, the gradient is
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{W}_2}=
\left[
(\mathbf{z}_2-\mathbf{t}) \circ \sigma'(\mathbf{h}_2) 
\right]
\mathbf{z}_1^T
$$
Note : the loss function was multiplied by $1/2$ in this case and $\circ$ means Hadamard product.